# Dudas con entity framework y las propiedades virtuales

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

ojala alguien me pudiera ayudar despejando algunas dudas que tengo con respecto a entity framewrok

1.-Al generar un modelo desde la base de datos, se genera el mapeo de las entidades pero se crean unas propiedades con la palabra reservada virtual....este virtual que es y como funciona en entity?..

2.- Al generar el modelo algunas de esas entidades virtuales se generan dos veces por que pasa esto?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿De casualidad no serán campos de la base computados? es decir no se insertan, sólo son de lectura. ¿Puedes poner fotos o código de lo que comentas?

Comment: Saludos Fernando, bienvenido a SOes, te recomiendo mirar https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla, por otro lado también revisa cómo realizar preguntas en: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask finalmente te recomiendo dar una lectura a la documentación oficial: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual si todavía quedan dudas, nos pasas la voz, cuando tienes 20 puntos de reputación puedes entrar al chat oficial de SOes :D

Comment: gracias fredyfx, voy a checar eso! :D

Comment: @shop350 a lo que me refiero es esto: en las clases generadas cuando creo el modelo edmx hay propiedades con este formato public virtual Orden Orden { get; set; }

Comment: Son virtuales porque Entity Framework crea objetos proxys con tus clases, es decir, Entity Framework, cuando va a instanciar datos desde tu base de datos usando tus clases, crea una clase virtual que hereda de tu clase, y sobrecarga esas propiedades agregando soporte al seguimiento de cambios automático, por ejemplo, si en tu clase entidad, leíste un registro y modificas una de sus propiedades y luego guardas cambios, entity framework solo va a ir a guardar los campos que cambiaron y no todos los campos. Si quitas la palabra virtual dejas de tener esa opción.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `virtual` permite que la libreria de `entity framework` sobreescriba la funcionalidad interponiendo un `proxy`, por ejemplo, para permitir que funcione el `lazy load` de las relaciones de navegacion entre las entidades.

[Cargar entidades relacionadas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)

En el articulo comenta:

> la carga diferida (lazy load) se logra mediante la creación de instancias de tipos proxy derivado y, a continuación, reemplazar propiedades virtuales para agregar el enlace de la carga

Por lo general si se duplica la entidad puede deberse a una incorrecta definicion en el mapping de la relacione entre las entidades, puede que se indique propiedades de `foreign key` que no representan la relacion